# How to change ctrl + tab on VSCode to tab between tabs like a browser does?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I hate those "last used" tabs things. I just want to go left/right in VSCode.

Answer (score 14):

I posted this answer how to bind the next/previous tab commands a couple of minutes ago here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40447042/2906632

Just bind the two commands from there to `ctrl-tab` and `ctrl-shift-tab`.

Comment: From the linked answer: "The commands for switching tabs are called workbench.action.nextEditor and workbench.action.previousEditor"

Answer (score 6):

I had to add do the following settings:

```json
    {
        "key": "ctrl+tab",
        "command": "workbench.action.nextEditor",
        "when": "!activeEditorGroupEmpty"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+tab",
        "command": "workbench.action.previousEditor",
        "when": "!activeEditorGroupEmpty"
    }
```

When clause taken from the defualts:

```json
    {
        "key": "ctrl+tab",
        "command": "-workbench.action.quickOpenPreviousRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup",
        "when": "!activeEditorGroupEmpty"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+tab",
        "command": "-workbench.action.quickOpenLeastRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup",
        "when": "!activeEditorGroupEmpty"
    }
```