# How to configure Visual studio code to use standard tab switching shortcut for mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

Most OS X applications with tabbed interface allow using `Cmd+Shift+[` and `Cmd+Shift+]` to switch tabs.

VSCode does not follow this. Is there a way to configure it to use these shortcuts to quickly switch to the next (towards right) and previous (towards left) tab.

This behavior is different from `Ctrl+Tab` behavior which shows a menu of most recent buffers. Repeatedly pressing `Ctrl+Tab` will keep alternating between same two recent buffers. But I would expect both `Cmd+Shift+[` or `Cmd+Shift+]` to cycle through all the tabs, in right to left and left to right direction respectively.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can bind every shortcut yourself if you want. Open you `keybindings.json` (via command palette or menu Code->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts).

Pressing `cmd+k cmd+k` gives you a little input field that prefills the correct JSON syntax.

The commands for switching tabs are called `workbench.action.nextEditor` and `workbench.action.previousEditor`